# Animate the View across the layout

Tags: android, android-animation, android-relativelayout

I trying to `animate` the `ImageView` from child layout `(Relativelayout)` to parent layout `(Relativelayout)`. Issue is `Imageview` is not getting painted while entering into the parent layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This R.anim.popup_show.xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

 <translate android:fromXDelta="100%p" android:toXDelta="0" android:duration="500"/>
    </set>
```

and apply in java file like as

```
   Animation animRight = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(options.this, R.anim.popup_show);
   ImageView.startAnimation( animRight );
```

Comment: need more clarification...pls

Comment: which view hv u want animate..?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/LayoutAnimation2.html

Comment: You have to mention question properly.